# Link library OpenSubdiv with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to make a C++ program that uses the OpenSubdiv library from Pixar: https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenSubdiv

I have managed to build the library, including the "tutorials", which uses the library.

Both OpenSubdiv and my own program is built with CMake (which I have some, but not much experince with). For testing purposes, I have a project folder where my C++ code lies, and I inside this folder I also have an OpenSubdiv folder where I have built the library in OpenSubdiv/build. The C++ code That I am using for testing purposes is identical to one of the tutorials provided by pixar with opensubdiv, called "far_tutorial_0.cpp". This tutorial compiles and work fine inside the Opensubdiv folder, with the very long and complex CMake script intended to install the entire library. However, when I move it out of the Opensubdiv folder, and try to compile with a simple CMake script, I get problems. This is the CMake script that I use:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (test)

add_executable(test test.cpp)

include_directories(OpenSubdiv/build)
target_link_libraries(test osdCPU)
```

This manages to compile the code without any error messages, but when I try to execute the code, it says "error while loading shared libraries: libosdCPU.so.3.0.0.beta: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

I have tried change the library name to "osdCPU.so.3.0.0.beta" (which gives an error while compiling), and I have tried using both library names (which gives the same error). The file "libosdCPU.so.3.0.0.beta" is inside the OpenSubdiv/build/lib folder, right next to "libosdCPU.so".

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to provide the location of the library `osdCPU` with the CMake command `link_directories`.

Moreover, I encourage you to formalize your code with specific variables like this (including a cache variable you can modify through the command `ccmake`) :

```
set(osdCPU_PATH_DEFAULT "/default/path/to/osdCPU")
set(osdCPU_PATH "${osdCPU_PATH_DEFAULT}" CACHE PATH "Path to osdCPU")
set(osdCPU_INCLUDE_DIRS ${osdCPU_PATH}/include)
set(osdCPU_LIBRARY_DIRS ${osdCPU_PATH}/lib)
set(osdCPU_LIBRARIES osdCPU)
```

Then you can call

```
include_directories(${osdCPU_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${osdCPU_LIBRARY_DIRS})
# ...
target_link_libraries(test ${osdCPU_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Hm, this did not fix the problem. Same thing happens :/ the code seems to compile fine, but when executed it complains about not beeing able to load "libosdCPU.so.3.0.0.beta".

Comment: Maybe you can add a simbolic link `libosdCPU.so` pointing to `libosdCPU.so.3.0.0.beta` in your system. You can do this by executing `ln -s libosdCPU.so.3.0.0.beta libosdCPU.so`.

Comment: I tried the same thing when I got home on my Mac (I was on ubuntu previously), and then it worked! Not sure whats wrong on my linux machine, but I guess there is something wrong with the way I installed the library, and not cmake/opensubdiv. Thanks for the help!